# Move DC motors with differents speed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm doing a project which I got to move two motors and they have differents movements. There are the codes:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO library
import time ## Import 'time' library. Allows us to use 'sleep'
import sys

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO Pin 11(motor b enable) to OUT
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)  ## Setup GPIO Pin 11(motor a enable) to OUT
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO Pin 11(motor a control) to OUT
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)  ## Setup GPIO Pin 11(motor a control) to OUT
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)   ## Setup GPIO Pin 11(motor b control) to OUT
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)    ## Setup GPIO Pin 11(motor b control) to OUT
GPIO.output(16, False)        ## disable motor a
GPIO.output(19, True)          ## enable motor b
p=GPIO.PWM(19,50)          ## frequency 50
p.start(1)
try:
    while True:
           GPIO.output(22, False)   ## dont run motor a
           GPIO.output(18, False)      ## dont run motor a
           GPIO.output(23, True)        ##  run motor b
           GPIO.output(21, False)         ##  run motor b
           p.ChangeDutyCycle(35)     ## duty cycle 10%
except KeyboardInterrupt:
     pass
p.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
sys.exit()
```

Code #2

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import sys

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

Motor1A = 22
Motor1B = 18
Motor1E = 16

Motor2A = 23
Motor2B = 21
Motor2E = 19

GPIO.setup(Motor1A,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Motor1B,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Motor1E,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(Motor2A,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Motor2B,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Motor2E,GPIO.OUT)

print "Going forwards"
GPIO.output(Motor1A,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(Motor1B,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(Motor1E,GPIO.HIGH)

GPIO.output(Motor2A,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(Motor2B,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(Motor2E,GPIO.HIGH)

sleep(2)




print "Now stop"
GPIO.output(Motor1E,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(Motor2E,GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.cleanup()
sys.exit()
```

I want to mix both codes in one. I mean, convert these two codes in one which has two differents speed.

Or If someone knows another code I'll be very thankful

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, use [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/api_output.html#motor), it's a lot more fun and turns your code into:

```
from gpiozero import Motor
from time import sleep

motorA = Motor(22, 18)  # your gpio pins go here
motorB = Motor(23, 21)

motorA.forward(0.5)  # half speed
motorB.forward(0.5)
sleep(2)  # wait 2 seconds before stopping the motors
motorA.stop()
motorB.stop()
```

Then, you can go a step further and use the `Robot` class instead (Documentation [here](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/api_boards.html#robot)), and make everything even easier:

```
from gpiozero import Robot
from time import sleep

robot = Robot(left=(22, 18), right=(23, 21))

robot.forward(1)  # full speed
sleep(2)
robot.stop()
```

The robot class also has some more functions, for example:

```
robot.left()
robot.right()
```

Most likely, you'll have to install the library first if you haven't used it yet. Type the following on the terminal in order to do so.

```
pip install gpiozero
```